# Steps in details to develop a sonar plugin

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I am just a beginner in this area because my major is automation and production. I just learned Java during the general courses, no any other languages.
However, now I am doing an internship, about developping a plugin sonar. (about the reason there is still a long history)

In fact, I have just learned what a database is after I began this internship. So I have a long long way to go

Is there any documentation in very details for the people like me? The official guide is not very detailed, i think...
eg: what kind of logiciel will I use to develop the plugin sonar? Eclipse?
    Fron which point could I begin this tough project?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First of all, adding "Urgent" to the topic name, will not get you quicker answers. Mostly the opposite is the case. That being said, do you already have a sonar server setup somewhere in your company or do they just want to start out using it?

Comment: Thanks for your noting. I didn't think too much when I wrote this title. Yes they have used it for some time. and now they are designing a platform, in fact it has been done and now what they want is to solve some little problems and to make it more perfect. And my subject--plugin sonar is just in this part..

Comment: If there is experience with sonar in your company, your project leader might be able to help you with the general layout (if he/she hasn't done so already). Other than that, try: [link](http://www.sonarsource.org/the-sonar-plugins-forge-is-up-and-running/)

Comment: Yes he has used that but he hasn't developped one plugin sonar. So this is the difficulty for me because I need to develop a plugin sonar from zero fro me...Whatever, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much experience you have with java. 
Do you know about basic OOP priciples like polymorphism and interfaces?

If not, I'd suggest you first read about those, because you are going to need them. After that start by setting up your development environment (you can use eclipse) and add the proper eclipse plugins for sonar development.

Then you can use the tutorial I linked in the comment.

Comment: Thanks A Lot! With Java, I think all I know is almost nothing. I just learned it during the commun course and did some small projects. I am not in the major of IT so all the information is so a lot and new to me.

Comment: You best start out [here](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmation_orient%C3%A9e_objet). And then google your way through to a decent course.

Comment: ^^ Yeah, I have read it just now. It's really something basic and I agree that i need to repick it up.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCamo what's the difference between a plugin sonar and a plugin eclipse?

Comment: an eclipse plugin is a plugin for the eclipse IDE. Eclipse can be configured to support the development of different "stuff" and extend eclipse's  features. for example there are plugins for android development, C++ develeopment and sonar plugin development. The sonar plugin is what you are going to develop to extend the features of your companies sonar server using eclipse.

Comment: thanks. and what i am wondering is the difference between the development of the 2 plugins. I have got and read some documentations for the plugin of eclipse. I am not sure whether it's helpful.

Comment: You don't need to develop the eclipse plugin. You can use the eclipse plugin to develop your sonar plugin.

Comment: Follow these [instructions](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar+in+Eclipse)

Comment: Ok, I have done this. so after I will need to create a project of sonar? or Maven? Why I need to install the sonar in my eclipse? it's for using sonar or developing plugin sonar? so many questions..thanks!

Comment: Rien. ;) We really should not continue this discussion here, because this is getting to much for this site and the comment section. I cannot guide you through the whole project step by step. If you have specific questions, ask them as new questions. One more advice though: Read some books on the subject.